# Can I Write the Below query using correlated "EXISTS"

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select first_name, department_id, salary   
from employees e1  
where salary > (select avg(salary) 
                from employees e2 
                where e2.department_id=e1.department_id )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can:

```
select first_name, department_id, salary
from employees e1
where exists (select 1
              from employees e2
              where e2.department_id = e1.department_id
              having e1.salary > avg(e2.salary)
             );
```

I find your version with the scalar subquery easier to understand, though.  And I don't think there is a difference in performance.